# How can i solve this problem of a Lexical Analyzer that is written in C++?

Tags: c++, lexical-analysis, keyword-search

I want to make a lexical analyzer using c++ that can -

1. remove single/multiline comments and produce the fresh text
2. identify keywords
3. identfy variables
4. identify special symbols
   from a text file as input of the program and finally output all of them in a separate text file as output from the program.

I have already coded the program. But It is unable to identfy the identifiers as variable and removing any commentline from the given text. My code is given below:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int isKeyword(char buffer[])
{
    char keywords[32][10] =
    {
        "auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default","do","double","else","enum","extern","float","for","goto","if","int","long","register","return","short","signed",
        "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union","unsigned","void","volatile","while"
    };
    int i, flag = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        if(strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    char ch, buffer[15], special[]=",;\(){}[]'':";
    ifstream My_input_file("D:\\input1.txt");
    ofstream My_output_file("D:\\output1.txt");
    int mark[1000]= {0};
    int i,j=0,kc=0,ic=0,sc=0;
    vector < string > k;
    vector<char >id;
    vector<char>sp;
    string line;
    int flag=1;
    if(My_input_file.is_open())
{
    while(getline(My_input_file,line))
    {
        int lenth=line.length(),i;
        char* newline = new char[lenth+1];
        strcpy(newline,line.c_str());
        for(i=0; i<lenth; i++)
        {
            if(newline[i]=='/'&& newline[i+1]=='/')
                break;
            if (newline[i]=='/'&& newline[i+1]=='*')
                flag=2;
            if (newline[i]=='*'&& newline[i+1]=='/')
                {flag=1;
                i++;}
            else if(flag==1)
            My_output_file<<newline[i];
        }
        My_output_file<<"\n";

    while(!My_input_file.eof())
    {
        ch = My_input_file.get();
        for(i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        {
            if(ch == special[i])
            {
                int aa=ch;
                if(mark[aa]!=1)
                {
                    sp.push_back(ch);
                    mark[aa]=1;
                    ++sc;
                }
            }
        }

        if(isalnum(ch))
        {
            buffer[j++] = ch;
        }
        else if((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') && (j != 0))
        {
            buffer[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;

            if(isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
            {

                k.push_back(buffer);
                ++kc;
            }
            else
            {
                if(buffer[0]>=97 && buffer[0]<=122)
                {
                    if(mark[buffer[0]-'a']!=1)
                    {
                        id.push_back(buffer[0]);
                        ++ic;
                        mark[buffer[0]-'a']=1;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
 }
}
    My_input_file.close();

    My_output_file<<"Keyword List: "<<endl;
    for(int f=0; f<kc; ++f)
    {
        if(f==kc-1)
        {
            My_output_file<<k[f]<<"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            My_output_file<<k[f]<<endl;
        }
    }
    My_output_file<<endl;
    My_output_file<<"Variable List: "<<endl;
    for(int f=0; f<ic; ++f)
    {
        if(f==ic-1)
        {
            My_output_file<<id[f]<<"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            My_output_file<<id[f]<<endl;
        }
    }
    My_output_file<<endl;
    My_output_file<<"Special Symbol List: "<<endl;
    for(int f=0; f<sc; ++f)
    {
        if(f==sc-1)
        {
            My_output_file<<sp[f]<<"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            My_output_file<<sp[f]<<endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using this text file as input. [Input Text File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQhLI.jpg)

After running this code into codeblock it produce the following output. [Output Text File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlVnf.jpg)

But, i want the output like this: [Output Required From the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQgVV.jpg)

**Where i am going wrong? Please help me to sort out.**

Comment: don't use images

Comment: _I have already coded the program. But It is unable to identfy the identifiers as variable and removing any commentline from the given text._ When you're done with coding you have to start with debugging. Did you?

Comment: From [ask]: _**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question._ (Emphasize _not_ mine.)

Comment: Why are you using `new char[lenth+1];` and `strcmp`? You already have a convenient `std::string line`, and then you just make it hard for yourself? Also, why are you trying to solve step (2) before you have step (1) working. It's probably easiest to define functions for all your steps. I.e. start writing `void removeComments(std::vector<std::string>&) {...`

Comment: Dear Sir, @MSalters, How and where i am put this code line that you have mentioned in your comment. Kindly do me a favor by writing the code line for me.

Comment: @SumonSaha: Check your textbook. I gave you the start of a function, but you will need to add more than just that one line. My suggestion here was not about one or two specific statements, but on the structure of your program. You should not write all code inside `main`. Instead, make clear functions for all the different steps.